# WCF: "Failed to open System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableDuplexSessionChannel"

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, timeout, wcf-binding

I currently have a WCF Service with a CallBack Contract (duplex), and when I use the application that makes use of it on my computer everything works fine, but when I try it from a different computer, it doesn't connect.

These problems started occurring once I switched to using this `wsDualHttpBinding` (for callbacks) because when I used `wsHttpBinding` everything worked fine.

Why is the web service not accepting requests from other computers?  Is it some hosting settings that need to be modified?

---

As regards the logs, I am getting these:

[alt text http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/4628/wcfissue.jpg](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/4628/wcfissue.jpg)

> The open operation did not complete
>   within the allotted timeout of
>   00:01:00. The time allotted to this
>   operation may have been a portion of a
>   longer timeout
>
> Failed to open System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableDuplexSessionChannel
>
> Faulted
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableDuplexSessionChannel
>
> Faulted
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel
>
> Failed to open
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel

---

The port is open on my router (both TCP and UDP) so that is not the issue.

As regards the Service Attributes, this is what I'm using:

*Interface:*

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "MusicRepo_DBAccess_Service", 
                 CallbackContract = typeof(IOnlineUsersCallback),
                 SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]
```

*Service:*

```
[ServiceBehavior(
        ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant, 
        InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

---

**[Update]**

As regards [Orion Edwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819871/wcf-failed-to-open-system-servicemodel-channels-clientreliableduplexsessionchann/837106#837106)' post:

- No Firewall
- See point 1
- Yes I can, because I have the port forwarded on my router
- I'm using IIS to host the server.

The thing is, this problem started happening when I switched from `wsHttpBinding` (which was working fine) to `wsDualHttpBinding` (because I needed callbacks)

---

**[Update]**

I have now switched from `wsDualHttpBinding` to `NetTcpBinding` and for some reason, everything is working fine.

I have used [this article](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Duplex_WCF_Services_Hosted_in_IIS_Using_NetTcp.aspx) to help me set up hosting on IIS, and thankully everything is working as expected, with callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now switched from `wsDualHttpBinding` to `NetTcpBinding` and for some reason, everything is working fine.

I have used [this article](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Duplex_WCF_Services_Hosted_in_IIS_Using_NetTcp.aspx) to help me set up hosting on IIS, and thankully everything is working as expected, with callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you posted the server and client configuration settings.

Here's a summary of how the wsDualHttpBinding works from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731821.aspx) (emphasise mine):

> The WSDualHttpBinding provides the
>   same support for Web Service protocols
>   as the WSHttpBinding, but for use with
>   duplex contracts. WSDualHttpBinding
>   only supports SOAP security and
>   requires reliable messaging. **This
>   binding requires that the client has a
>   public URI that provides a callback
>   endpoint for the service. This is
>   provided by the clientBaseAddress
>   attribute.** A dual binding exposes the
>   IP address of the client to the
>   service. The client should use
>   security to ensure that it only
>   connects to services it trusts.
>
> This binding can be used to
>   communicate reliably through one or
>   more SOAP intermediaries.
>
> By default, this binding generates a
>   runtime stack with
>   WS-ReliableMessaging for reliability,
>   WS-Security for message security and
>   authentication, HTTP for message
>   delivery, and a Text/XML message
>   encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- Windows Firewall
- Your antivirus product's firewall
- Can you telnet into the port from a remote machine?
- Is your "server" running under the ASP.NET development server? That will only accept requests from localhosts - you need to self-host the server using `ServiceHost` or host it under IIS.